# Text is showing in one phone but not on another phone when running app fron android studio

Tags: android, textview

I have one phone which is Samsung M51 and another is a lava iris model. When I run the app in lava, it runs normally but doesn't show text view, on another hand when it runs on Samsung, it runs without any problem. Why these two different results having the same code.[Code in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLCIX.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please [include in your question post everything needed to invite useful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - hyperlinks welcome for reference&detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using hardcoded margins which are almost 700dp, Lava Iris's screen size is too small for these margins.
You should use a proper layout (e.g. [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)) to place the TextView on the screen.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks brother. I changed the value and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not quietly sure, but probably the main reason is huge values of `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginBottom`.

Try to use layout constraints instead of margins to place your `TextView`s.